# Circular dependency error in relative layout.

Tags: android, android-layout, runtime-error, android-relativelayout

I am trying to use custom buttons in a relative layout, but on runtimr I am facing this circular dependency error from relative layout, Can someone guide me on this? When I use Linear Layout (after code alterations) it works fine.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/settingsBtn"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Play"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/settingsBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rulesBtn"
    android:layout_below="@id/playBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/rulesBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/exitBtn"
    android:layout_below="@id/settingsBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Rules"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@id/exitBtn"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rulesBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a button that is above another implies that the second is below the first, you needn't specify both.

Remove:

```
android:layout_below="@id/playBtn"
```

also

```
 android:layout_below="@id/settingsBtn"
```

and

```
android:layout_below="@id/rulesBtn"
```

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` uses things like above, below, toLeftOf, toRightOf.  You could logically say "X is left of Y; Y is right of X".  It makes sense, but it doesn't say exactly where one ends and the other begins.  When you do that, the parser doesn't know how to lay out the values.  So, you just say "X is left of Y".  Then it'll layout Y first (taking whatever space it's configured to take without considering X), and put X to the left of it.

Short answer: use `layout_above` or `layout_below` to define a relationship, but never both.